# Windows Application connect using Public IP to SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql

I have develop Software which is successfully run with Local SQL Server.
But my client need it access over the internet.

How i make connect application with database using public ip.

I have try with following connection string. but still i can not log.
connectionString="Data Source=XXX.XXX.XXX.X\XXX,7000;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=sa;Password=xxx"

Is there any SQL Server configuration, Router Configuration etc.

Answer (score 2):

[You don't expose a database over the internet, it's highly insecure](https://serverfault.com/questions/306053/how-to-make-sql-server-visible-on-internet).

Create a webservice that talks to the database, and let your application talk to the webservice.

If you really don't care about security or your client's data (and I'm sure they won't like that), you can. You just need to forward the proper ports in your router.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your are able to connect to remote sql from your local sql server.

To connect to remote sql try this

You have to open port for it. After opening port your server name looks like follow.

```
server name : IP\SqlExpress, 5012
```

Where **5012** is random port.

Refer this to open port for sql on remote
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx